# Binding Varialbes in XAML with VB Code Behind

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Seems this would be an easy solution but i've been banging my head over it for over a week.
All I want to do is set the XAML variable to a different color from the VB code behind

In my Application.xaml I define a Solid Color Brush, then use that Brush to define a style:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BrushBG"  x:Key="KeyMainBrush" Color="White"/>
    <Style x:Name="styleGridBG" x:Key="GridBGColor" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource KeyMainBrush}"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

In my Main Window XAML I have a grid using that style

```
<Grid x:Name="grdColor" Style="{DynamicResource GridBGColor}" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="77" Margin="205,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="493" />
```

In my MainWindow VB I want to change that color to Red when a radio button is checked.   I can read the color, but do not know how to write the color:

```
Private Sub rdRed_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles rdRed.Checked
    MsgBox(Me.FindResource("KeyMainBrush").ToString)
    DataContext(Me.FindResource("KeyMainBrush")) = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
End Sub
```

I get an error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object variable or With block variable not set.'

Comment: You can't reference objects in code behind without that object having a runat="server" So, adding that attribute (runat="server") to the grid control on the form should allow you to reference and use that grid object from vb code. Now I just noticed that this is not asp.net - so  I may well be wrong here.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, "this is not asp.net - so I may well be wrong here" - yes. WPF doesn't have concept of runat="server"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need FindResource or DataContext. just add necessary Brush into Resources:

```
Private Sub rdRed_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles rdRed.Checked
    Me.Resources("KeyMainBrush") = Brushes.Red;
End Sub
```

also note, that in order to see change in UI, you should reference KeyMainBrush as DynamicResource in Style. StaticResources is resolved at compile-time and doesn't change in runtime after modifications

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BrushBG"  x:Key="KeyMainBrush" Color="White"/>
    <Style x:Name="styleGridBG" x:Key="GridBGColor" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource KeyMainBrush}"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

at the same time Style can be set as StaticResource - resource doesn't change:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdColor" Style="{StaticResource GridBGColor}"
```

Comment: That was it.  Thanks so much ASh